# Setting Groups/Permissions in iron-router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to set up group permissions with iron:router. The way I came up with was to set a group key in the user's profile, and then check that value vs the group that has access to the given section of a site via an onBeforeAction hook. See example:

hooks.js:

```
beforehooks = {
  checkGroup: function(group) {
    if (Meteor.user().profile.group === group) {
      this.next();
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  }
}
```

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('managers', {
    path: '/managers',
    onBeforeAction: beforehooks.checkGroup("managers")
  });
});
```

This keeps causing an error that is preventing meteor from starting up, but I am not sure what it is. Am I doing something wrong with passing variables through a JavaScript method call? (side note: I just discovered the roles package and plan on looking into it tomorrow. However, I would still like to learn what the error is here)

Additional Info/Edit: If I remove the group variable from the checkGroup method, and hard code a string into the 'if' statement, everything works fine. I will try to get something into MeteorPad today.

Additional Edit: Here are two Meteorpads, one with working code, and one with the error (by passing a variable to the hook)

working code:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/PdP4v7qtM79Xi6FDQ/Groups%20-%20Functioning

code w/ error:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/bMTqeA39GqSQee9KC/Groups%20-%20Error

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: It's exiting with a code 8 and the following:

Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping **beforehooks** inside an **Meteor.isClient** block?

Comment: Tried that. No luck :-/ I don't know enough about iron-router internals, but it seems to be an issue with passing a variable and accessing Meteor.user().

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should remove the comma after the **onBeforeAction**, add a closing parenthesis and semicolon on the following line, and also a semicolon on the last line:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('managers', {
    path: '/managers',
    onBeforeAction: beforehooks.checkGroup("managers")
  });
});
```

**It would be much easier for someone to help you if you posted your code to http://meteorpad.com.**

Comment: It would also be good to post the data from your **Users** collection.

Comment: You can debug by replacing the actual function to onBeforeAction. Hope that useful.

Comment: Thanks for catching those bugs, I'll edit the post. Unfortunately they aren't related to my error...just an error posting here.